# How can I set authentication required for access AWS DynamoDB

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

First I simply follow the given instruction for accessing the [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html),
After that I build the downloaded sample project named **[DynamoDBObjectMapper-Sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples)** I got given error log -

***Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.}***

This error are print after executing following code-

```
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
        queryExpression.exclusiveStartKey = self.lastEvaluatedKey
        queryExpression.limit = 20
        dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(DDBTableRow.self, expression: queryExpression).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

            if self.lastEvaluatedKey == nil {
                self.tableRows?.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
            }

            if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
                for item in paginatedOutput.items as! [DDBTableRow] {
                    self.tableRows?.append(item)
                }

                self.lastEvaluatedKey = paginatedOutput.lastEvaluatedKey
                if paginatedOutput.lastEvaluatedKey == nil {
                    self.doneLoading = true
                }
            }

            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

            return nil
        })
```

So please help me for set the authentication key-

Comment: What are the IAM privileges you are using with this program? Does it have access to DynamoDB? Also what version of swift are you running?

Comment: I am new in aws , so I am didn't have enough knowledge about IAM. Yes it access DynamoDB. I am using swift 4.0.